# Required Validation Control in a hidden controls asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have 20 controls in my .net user control which is deployed as a SharePoint visual web part.

so the values of my controls determine the visibility of other controls in the page.

I also have to use required validation, for this i am thinking to use .net required validation

my question is if a control is hidden then does the required validation of that control is checked. 
When i do the validation in my button, if the control is hidden does it still check the required validation to be checked. if it checks then i will never made this to work.

Any ideas just confused....

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Strange question: "my question is if a control is hidden then does the required validation of that control is checked"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF a control is hidden it doesn't check the validation of that control, however if a control is disabled then the validation controls also needs to be disabled, else it will always check the validation.